# SLDS -pageblocktable not responsive inside an outputPanel

Tags: slds, pageblocktable

I am using SLDS in existing VF page and I also want the page to be responsive. In the code below the outputPanel is responsive but the pageblock table within it is not responsive and it extends out of the outPutPanel. Any idea how to achieve this?  Ideally I need to get a horizontal scroll bar when the output panel becomes narrow. Please see the screen shot and corresponding code below for standard Contact object. Earlier I forgot to mention that this all is happening in a modal window.

[image]

Comment: We are unable to visualize the problem, please add some screenshots and post the minimal code with any standard objects; with that it would be easier for us to replicate the issue..

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and added inline style to the modal container of the pageblock table so it shows the scrollbar and not extending out of the modal container.